# Which design pattern is it? Can't recognize

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a situation, where I have to call my methods in particular
order. This came up in multiple places, so I wonder if there's some pattern I can't see.

Right now in every such case, I have prepare stage **where I execute some code based on preconditions**, an act stage (where I modify my data) and save stage where I save it to the db. 
I now have this:

```
accessRightsService.Shift(document, userRole);
updateService.ApplyChanges(document, newData);
documentRepository.Update(document);
```

I was thinking about something like `myService.WrapOperation(doc, d => {})` that would call prepare first, then execute the action, then save results to the database.

**So, is it a pattern - and if it is, which one?**

Doesn't look like template method or decorator to me

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern or http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern

Comment: Could you provide a example of the code

Comment: @Eldho just did so

Comment: The Strategy pattern might fit in what you're trying to do (https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy).

Comment: Maybe the `Command` pattern might help you here. You could have a `CommandExecutor` object that takes in a list of `Commands`. Then you can call `CommandExecutor.Execute()` which will iterate through each `Command`, in the order they were added, calling the `.Execute()` function on those.

Comment: Not to diminish their usefulness, but : The world is __not__ completely  made up of design patterns.

Comment: @TaW completely true. I just want to make sure I didn't miss a widely known solution here

Comment: @TaW you are correct but these patterns are useful in software engineering to tackle common scenarios and also other developers can identify them and see why they are used.

Comment: Yes they are very useful, no argument here. It is just that you can't expect them to cover everything you meet or need. Still a good question to look at in many situations, imo..

Comment: @TaW the example code is really Bad(tm) though since there is a secret temporal coupling. there is no way at all to know by just inspecting the method signatures that they depend on each other and that they have to be called in a certain order. some refactoring is needed here.

Comment: Most design patterns can be eliminated through well factored code. Design patterns can be useful in the correct situations, but you should not be searching for chances to implement specific patterns. As @kai mentioned above, maybe you should consider refactoring.

Comment: Are you just encountering repeated code you can extract to a method? http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html

Answer (score 1):

This closely resembles the ***Builder*** pattern. Even though the builder pattern states that it is used for class instantiation this can also be applied for method calls.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Builder.aspx

```
public class Director
{
    public void Construct(Builder builder)
    {
        builder.BuildPart1();
        builder.BuildPart2();
        builder.BuildPart3();
    }
}


public abstract class Builder
{
    public abstract void BuildPart1();
    public abstract void BuildPart2();
    public abstract void BuildPart3();
    public abstract Product GetProduct();
}


public class ConcreteBuilder : Builder
{
    private Product _product = new Product();

    public override void BuildPart1()
    {
        _product.Part1 = "Part 1";
    }

    public override void BuildPart2()
    {
        _product.Part2 = "Part 2";
    }

    public override void BuildPart3()
    {
        _product.Part3 = "Part 3";
    }

    public override Product GetProduct()
    {
        return _product;
    }
}


public class Product
{
    public string Part1 { get; set; }
    public string Part2 { get; set; }
    public string Part3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this looks similar to template method, only here you define step order in client code